# Usage of "bei" in "Es bleibt bei..."

Tags: sentence-structure, phrase

In an official paper from a government financial agency, I have encountered the following sentence:

*"Stornoraten: es bleibt bei den bisherigen Annahmen."*

Why is there **bei** in the sentence? Could the author have used *"Stornoraten: es bleiben die bisherigen Annahmen."* instead, and would it have the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the phrasal verb *bleiben bei*+dative that has a slightly different meaning than a plain *bleiben*. Compare *to stay with* and *to stay*.

There's also a separable verb *dabeibleiben — to stay with that* with the same meaning that doesn't take a prepositional object *bei*+dative

> Es bleibt bei den bisherigen Annahmen.

> Es bleibt dabei.

Comment: Danke vielmals für deine Antwort!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the meaning is the same. The formulation with "bei" is a bit more formal and allows keeping the object in the same (dative) form as before.

> Bleibt es bei der aktuellen Regelung?
> Ja, es bleibt bei der aktuellen Regelung.

Otherwise, a grammatical adjustment is required:

> Ja, es bleibt die aktuelle Regelung.

or

> Ja, es bleiben die aktuellen Regeln.

Comment: Danke vielmals für deine Antwort!